# How do i get custom UIView in table view cell

Tags: ios

I have a Custom `UIView` inside my prototype cell in a nd iOS 8.2 app before it was a regular UIImage and i was getting it back fine with [currentCell viewWithTag:200]; inside my `UITableView` `cellForRowIndexPath` method. But after i have made a custom uiview and replaced the uiimage it always returns nil..

*edit*
After trying to add a new label to a working menu controller that is way more simple just loops over a array of strings. and setting the tag and in the loop (that is already printing the correct value out for the menu) it can't find the newly added label. is it possible to somehow not get the tags compiled ?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *currentCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
Lists *listItem = [lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if(currentCell == nil){
    currentCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

//THIS ALLWAYS RETUNS nil
ShadedBadgeImage *cellImage = (ShadedBadgeImage *)[currentCell viewWithTag:200];
//UIView *cellImage = (UIView *)[currentCell viewWithTag:200];
//cellImage.completedProcentage = 2.0 * listItem.id.doubleValue;


UILabel *cellTitle = (UILabel *) [currentCell viewWithTag:101];
UILabel *cellDescription = (UILabel *)[currentCell viewWithTag:102];

cellTitle.text = listItem.id.stringValue;
cellDescription.text = listItem.shortText;

return currentCell;
```

And my custom uiview. that is using the layoutSubviews to render the masked image and progress bar.

IB_DESIGNABLE

```
@implementation ShadedBadgeImage {

    double lineWidth;
    CAShapeLayer *backgroundLayer;
    CAShapeLayer *coloredLayer;
    CALayer *imageLayer;

}
    - (void)baseInit {
        lineWidth = 5.0;
        [self updateStroke];
    }

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {

        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            [self baseInit];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
        if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
            [self baseInit];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)layoutSubviews {
        [super layoutSubviews];

        //Adds the background ring layer
        if(backgroundLayer == nil)
        {
            backgroundLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

            CGRect rect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, lineWidth/2.0, lineWidth/2.0);
            UIBezierPath *roundPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];

            backgroundLayer.path = roundPath.CGPath;
            backgroundLayer.fillColor = nil;
            backgroundLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth;
            backgroundLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.05].CGColor;

            [self.layer addSublayer:backgroundLayer];
        }
        backgroundLayer.frame = self.layer.frame;

        //Adds the color ring layer
        if(coloredLayer == nil)
        {
            coloredLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

            CGRect rect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, lineWidth/2.0, lineWidth/2.0);
            UIBezierPath *roundPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];

            coloredLayer.path = roundPath.CGPath;
            coloredLayer.fillColor = nil;
            coloredLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth;
            coloredLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

            coloredLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
            coloredLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(coloredLayer.transform, -M_PI/2, 0, 0, 1);

            [self.layer addSublayer:coloredLayer];
        }
        coloredLayer.frame = self.layer.frame;

        //Adds the color ring layer
        if(imageLayer == nil)
        {
            CAShapeLayer *imageMask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
            CGRect insertBounds = CGRectInset(self.bounds, lineWidth + 3.0, lineWidth + 3.0);
            UIBezierPath *innerPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:insertBounds];

            imageMask.path = innerPath.CGPath;
            imageMask.fillColor =  [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
            imageMask.frame = self.bounds;
            [self.layer addSublayer:imageMask];


            imageLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
            imageLayer.mask = imageMask;
            imageLayer.frame = self.layer.frame;
            imageLayer.backgroundColor =[UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
            imageLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;

            [self.layer addSublayer:imageLayer];
        }
        [self updateStroke];
    }

    - (void) updateStroke{
        if (coloredLayer != nil)
        {
            coloredLayer.strokeEnd = self.completedProcentage;
        }

        if(self.image != nil)
        {
            imageLayer.contents = (__bridge id)([self.image CGImage]);
        }
    }   
    @end
```

Comment: Please format your code. Are you setting the tag?

Comment: i am sitting the tag yes, and trying to format the code :)

Comment: Where are you making your cell? Is the if(currentCell == nil) clause being executed? Using tags like this is kind of clunky -- create a custom class instead, and make IBOutlets for your views (or properties if you create them in code).

Comment: as rdelmar says, dont go down the road with tags. I cleared all my tags redidt em so i was sure no dublicates was there, and still nothing worked, if i changede the once that was working to a new tag identify they still worked. I have no clue on what went wrong inside the story board. but used the entire night to exchange all cells with custom classes. and now it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

As the comments says, dont use tags go for custom UITableCellViews for more control